# Feasibility of making a synchronous call to FIleSystem from chrome.webRequest callbacks set up as "blocking"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, blocking, synchronous, html5-filesystem

I am writing a Chrome extension which listens for `chrome.webRequest` events, some are set up for blocking, so that I can cancel the request.  I need to be able to make a SYNCHRONOUS call from within the `chrome.webRequest` callback, which writes to the HTML5 FileSystem.  Is there any way to accomplish this synchronously, i.e., so that I have my result of the `FileWrite` before I return from the `chrome.WebRequest` callback?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

Some `webRequest` calls can be made synchronous, but file operations in FileSystem API are asynchronous and JS can't "wait" for async operations in a blocking manner.

Comment: How about using a synchronous PPAPI call from the webRequest callback instead of using the FileSystem API?  Would that be possible?  If so, how does one implement a synchronous PPAPI call?  Is there any other mechanism you could recommend?

Comment: That is outside of my area of expertise, sorry.